# JavaFx 12 Spring, Maven No plugin found for prefix

Tags: spring, maven, javafx

I have a problem trying to debug a project with javafx and spring

my pom. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>javafx</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my main:

> ```
> @Override
> public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     context = SpringApplication.run(JavafxApplication.class);
>     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(JavafxApplication.class.getResource("/Home.fxml"));
>     loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
>     Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
>     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
>     primaryStage.show();
> }
> ```

I have these errors when trying to compile with maven:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [WARNING] The POM for
>   org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency
>   information available [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor
>   for org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0: Plugin
>   org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies
>   could not be resolved: Failure to find
>   org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping:jar:1.0.0 in
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced [INFO]
>   Downloading from :
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
>   [INFO] Downloading from :
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
>   [INFO] Downloaded from :
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
>   (14 kB at 9.1 kB/s) [INFO] Downloaded from :
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
>   (20 kB at 12 kB/s) [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  2.867 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2019-08-08T01:13:18-03:00 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'javafx' in the current project and
>   in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local
>   (C:\Users\Gabriel.m2\repository), central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

I went to run configurations and make this:

[image]

Comment: You need to add the `javafx-maven-plugin` to your pom if you want `javafx:run` to work... See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse (Maven sections).

Comment: The plugin is required to manage the JavaFX dependencies and run your project. It should deal with other dependencies (Spring) as well. Give it a try.

Comment: @JoséPereda thanks man now i got erros with springboot

Comment: If you want to add the answer so I can set as a solution.

Comment: I've posted an answer, that also includes a small sample with JavaFX (FXML) and Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pom you have posted is missing the `javafx-maven-plugin`. As documented here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse (Maven section), you need to include it in order to deal with the JavaFX dependencies (including them in the module-path, adding the required modules), while keeping the rest of dependencies in the classpath (if your project is non-modular).

And if you want to run the goal `javafx:run`, as posted in the picture, you do need the plugin that defines this goal.

This works for me (JavaFX + Spring):

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Main class**

```
package org.openjfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class);
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("scene.fxml"));

        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**FXMLController**

```
package org.openjfx;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class FXMLController {

    public void initialize() {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

Now you can run from the console:

```
mvn clean javafx:run
```

or add a goal to Run configurations -> `Maven Build`: `clean javafx:run`.

You should see your JavaFX app working, and also the Spring output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)

2019-08-08 18:29:44.025  INFO 8648 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Starting application on mac.local with PID 8648 (started by user in /path/to/Maven/hellofx)
2019-08-08 18:29:44.028  INFO 8648 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-08 18:29:44.524  INFO 8648 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 0.787 seconds (JVM running for 1.577)
```

Comment: You can add an EDIT at the end of your original post, and add those errors, sure.

Comment: I managed I had forgotten to add my style.xml
could you ask me one more question? When I close the application it remains open in the processes how could I solve it?

Comment: See my full `MainApp` code (and the call to `springContext.stop();`)

Comment: I did just like that
so in case I can put a system exit in the stop method?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, you should find the running threads and try to stop them properly instead. System.exit is a last resource of course.

Comment: Oops sorry could you ask me a question about debug?
With this maven is not possible to debug?
I tried debugging with breakpoints in close and it didn't work

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56207033/3956070) is for Maven and NetBeans, but will work as well for Eclipse.

Comment: thanks man 
About controllers I just need public void initialize () {
        // TODO
    }
no implements Initializable and @Override
    public void initialize (URL url, ResourceBundle rb)?

Comment: Both are valid, but the former is usually the preferred one.